# EnsEMBL Perl API connection error

Tags: perl

I just posted this on Biostars but I think it's probably more appropriate here.

I am trying to use the EnsEMBL Perl API. Last week this worked perfectly from the host I am using. I've come back to it a week later, with nothing changing in the meantime to this error.

From the API webpage, my code contains the following:

```
Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry->load_registry_from_db(
  -host    => 'ensembldb.ensembl.org',
  -user    => 'anonymous',
  -verbose => '1'
);
```

This used to work fine, but the error I get now is:

```
-------------------- EXCEPTION --------------------
MSG: Cannot connect to the Ensembl MySQL server at ensembldb.ensembl.org:3306; check your settings & DBI error message: Host **<IP address redacted>** is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry::load_registry_from_db ../ensembl/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/Registry.pm:1769
STACK toplevel ./connect.pl:13
Date (localtime)    = Mon May  7 16:21:29 2018
Ensembl API version = 92
---------------------------------------------------
```

I connected to my local mysql and performed FLUSH HOSTS like it asked, but it didn't help. I have also tried to look through previous posts to see if this has happened before - which it has, with BiomaRt, when ensembl changed something.

Does this error happen for other people or just me? I am trying to figure out if this is on my end or ensembl's end. When I use the ping_ensembl.pl script it has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any replies to this but it is okay. I am posting the follow up to this just in case anyone comes across this problem in the future.

The issue resolved itself overnight. The problem wasn't on my end.